# Getting result from SQL Server query to a list<T> object

Tags: c#, sql-server, class, user-defined-types

I have a query in SQL Server as:

```
SELECT   
    AC.Author_ID, AC.CoAuthor_ID, AC.Paper_ID, AP.Venue_ID, AC.Year
FROM
    AuthorCoAuthor AC
JOIN     
    AuthorPaper AP ON AP.Author_ID = AC.Author_ID 
                   AND AP.Paper_ID  = AC.Paper_ID
WHERE    
    AC.Year = 2005
ORDER BY 
    AC.Author_ID, AC.Year, AC.CoAuthor_ID, AC.Paper_ID, AP.Venue_ID
```

which returns these results:

```
Author_ID | CoAuthor_ID | Paper_ID | Venue_ID | Year
----------------------------------------------------
677       | 901706      | 812229   | 64309    | 2005  
677       | 901706      | 812486   | 65182    | 2005
677       | 901706      | 818273   | 185787   | 2005
1359      | 133112      | 812558   | 65182    | 2005
1359      | 133112      | 1346914  | 99789    | 2005  
...       | ...         | ...      | ...      | ...  
...       | ...         | ...      | ...      | ...
```

How can I get all this output in single object of a class i.e. `Author.cs` the code for `Author.cs` is as:

```
public partial class Author
{
    public Author()
    {
        this.AuthorCoAuthors = new HashSet<AuthorCoAuthor>();
        this.AuthorPapers = new HashSet<AuthorPaper>();
        this.AuthorVenues = new HashSet<AuthorVenue>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Author_ID { get; set; }
    public string Author_Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AuthorCoAuthor> AuthorCoAuthors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AuthorPaper> AuthorPapers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AuthorVenue> AuthorVenues { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I define a List of type `Author` as:

```
List<Author> _author = new List<Author>();
```

How can I read all above output in `_author`?

Comment: You mean array of Author() right?

Comment: @KunalChitkara yeah obviously

Comment: Do you need to create the `AuthorCoAuthor`, `AuthorPaper`, and `AuthorVenue` objects?   Also what's the difference between the `ID` and `Auther_ID` properties of the `Author` class?  Seems like this would be a good place to use EF.

Comment: @juharr Yeah I need the `_author` i.e. object of `List<Author>` should contain `Author_ID`, `CoAuthor_ID`, `Paper_ID` and `Venue_ID` for a given `Year`. The difference between `ID` and `Author_ID` is: `ID` (the PK) has values starting from `1,2,3....` and so on whereas values for `Author_ID` has been shown in example output. The code shown for class `Author.cs` is *auto-generated* code got by using Entity Framework.

Comment: @juharr are you looking it more ?

Comment: So, are you asking for the Linq-to-EF equivalent of your SQL then?

Comment: @juharr yeah because I have to process `_author` list for clustering afterwards after getting it filled from SQL Server while the `Year` be passed as a parameter for which I have written two stored procedures as: `GetAuthorsByYear` and `GetAuthorsBetweenYears` as well.